# Way to track all functions in Visual Studio / Nice debugger for VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-c++, callstack

1)There is **call stack** provided in VS but isn't always show the sequence of functions called by user's code.It just shows functions from windows & directly the function you put break point on & not all functions called till then.

2) **Call hierarchy** also isn't much helpful.

Comment: You will be hard-pressed to find a better integrated debugger for Windows than the one packaged in Visual Studio. It sounds to me like your issue with #1 is message-loop related or optimized code. A [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) would go a long way in demonstrating the behavior your seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can define two macros

```
#define IN std::cout<<std::string(__FUNCTION__)<<" begins.."<<std::endl;
#define OUT std::cout<<std::string(__FUNCTION__)<<" ends.."<<std::endl;
```

Use these macros at the beginning and end of each functions. This will print the entire flow.

Comment: Eww. AT the very least use `OutputDebugString`. But you don't need to insert these macro's. The compiler can automatically insert calls to `_penter` and `_pexit` (`/Gh and /GH`)